# Are all words stripped of bikago when listed in dictionaries?

Tags: dictionary, bikago

When checking dictionaries (jisho.org and Wiktionary) for お名前, I found that it wasn't listed as お名前, but only as 名前. Do most dictionaries strip bikago from all words, or do they typically strip bikago only from some words?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that the お and ご prefixes are included when the resulting word has been *lexicalized* and is no longer simply a combination of the prefix and the bare word.

For example, I see entries for [おやすみ](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8A%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%BF&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss), [おにぎり](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8A&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss) and [ごはん](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%94%E9%A3%AF&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss) in 大辞林.  I think these words were originally combinations of お and ご with 休み, 握り, and 飯（はん）, but the combinations became words in their own right, so they have their own entries.

Words like お名前 don't have separate entries because there's no need.  お名前 is simply the combination of お and 名前.